# Java: Thread on Event every specific time interval (Issue Observer inside Thread: EventSource.run() method runs in an infinite loop)

Tags: java, multithreading, observable

I'm doing a thread who tells me when an event happens. I think that thread is not necessary if event can be controlled by timer for example. But I need an event every minute. Trouble are two:
1. When event is inside a thread occurs too fast. It seems like loop over thread. But threads are necessary to listen or catch an event.
2. I can't tell method which custom object must dispatch event, and then capture this event from a new class
I hope that you can help, here is code:

```
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Observable;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Threading test = new Threading();
        test.start();
    }
}

class ResponseHandler implements Observer {

    @Override
   public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof String) {
            String resp = (String) arg;
            System.out.println("\n Received response: " + resp);
        }
    }
}

class EventSource extends Observable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Object msg = new Object(); //I guess that this must have an object here, that throws a timeout
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}

class Obj {

    EventSource _eventSource;
    ResponseHandler _responseHandler;

    public Obj() {
        try {
            _eventSource = new EventSource();
            _responseHandler = new ResponseHandler();
            _eventSource.addObserver(_responseHandler);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
    }
}

class Threading extends Obj implements Runnable {

    Thread _thread;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                _eventSource.run(); //Event which never stops
                Thread.sleep(1000); //hey thread what are you doing?

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("Thread");
        }
    }
    //Singlethon
    public void start() {
        if (_thread == null) {
            _thread = new Thread(this);
            _thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the issues you are having?

Comment: Your EventSource.run() method runs in an infinite loop without any wait/sleep/whatever.

Comment: Yes, an Infinite loop on EventSource.run() witch is inside thread